# ViewData.ModelState.IsValid check firing for all (partial) forms contained in one razor view

Tags: razor, view, modelstate

I have two forms on my homepage (a contact form and a competition form which are both partials), both have separate controllers and models.

In both partials i have the following code which displays an error message if the email fails to send.

```
if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <div class="form-failure">
        <h4><i class="fa fa-close"></i>@Model.FailureTitle</h4>
        @Html.Raw(Model.FailureContent)
    </div>
```

Email error code in both controllers

```
            if (emailService.Send(EmailMessageBuilder.BuildUserEmail(model.FullName, model.EmailAddress, model.PhoneNumber)) != EmailState.Success)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "There was a problem sending the Email. Please try again later, or call us.");
                return CurrentUmbracoPage();
            }
```

The problem is the error displays on both forms because the !ViewData.ModelState.IsValid returns the same result for both. How can I ensure that the error only displays on the form which the request has been submitted from?

```
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store which form it is in ViewData

```
if (emailService.Send(EmailMessageBuilder.BuildUserEmail(model.FullName, model.EmailAddress, model.PhoneNumber)) != EmailState.Success)
{
    ViewData["Form"] = "Form1";
    ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "There was a problem sending the Email. Please try again later, or call us.");
    return CurrentUmbracoPage();
}
```

Then check in the html to see which form is invalid

```
if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid && ViewData["Form"] == "Form1" )
{
     ....
}
```